# dialog unknown issue in google play services when try to use Google Drive sample

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-play-services

I Google more then 4 hour but not getting the solution. I register my app pkg and hash key in app console. I am using sample provided by Google developers. But what happening I don't know.

not able to post and image due to less reputation

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have added your package name and key SHA1 at

*Google Cloud Console → Your Project → API & auth → Credentials* via “Create New Client ID” at “OAuth” section.

I got the same result as you described when added information via “Create New Key” at “Public API access” section.

The procedure is described at [documentation steps 7 and 8](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/get-started#get_an_android_certificate_and_register_your_application).

Comment: It helped me. The Public API access key worked for my debug apk, but not for release apk. Right after I created the New Client ID (OAuth) things started working. Very poor information from Google about when to use which and about how to list which certificates are active etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you sure package name and key SHA1 is ok, check CLIENT. May not have all the services are enabled but you use CLIENT_ALL.

CLIENT_ALL=

```
gameHelper = new GameHelper(gameActivity, GameHelper.CLIENT_GAMES | GameHelper.CLIENT_PLUS
            | GameHelper.CLIENT_APPSTATE | GameHelper.CLIENT_SNAPSHOT);
```

Use  same CLIENT_APPSTATE:

```
gameHelper = new GameHelper(gameActivity,CLIENT_APPSTATE);
```

Little by little add CLIENT and check which one CLIENT cause dialog.

Answer (score 0):

In the developer's console, make sure that your project's consent screen 'email address' and 'product name' fields are set. I was getting this error until I provided valid values for these fields.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using SHA key of my release version instead of build version's SHA key.