# Google drive unknown issue with google play services

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I have been trying to connect to Google Drive from emulator,  I have done the Google API registration.  It is strange that, if I run on the mobile device, it runs without problem,
but if it run under emulator, it prompt

> unknown issue with google play services

in  the logcat the error is:

```
06-22 06:25:03.685: I/BaseDriveActivity(2547): GoogleApiClient connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=unknown status code 1500, resolution=null}
```

The `mGoogleApiClient.connect();` seem to give this error.  I can't seem to debug further.

```
 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
 if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(Drive.API)
                    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER) // required for App Folder sample
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();
        }
        //if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
...
```

I have tried the following, it doesn't seem to help.
[dialog unknown issue in google play services when try to use Google Drive sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403454/dialog-unknown-issue-in-google-play-services-when-try-to-use-google-drive-sample)

Comment: have you registred the app on the console both for debug and release?

Comment: yes i did.  i registered both.  is there any where i can't check what is the deployed sha1 key in emulator?